# Бритвенно(-)острый

Tags: слитно-дефис

Слитно или через дефис? Бритвенно(-)острый

Answer (score 1):

***Бритвенно-острый топор*** (хороший, прочный, можно купить).

Это игровой термин http://wowmanual.ru/?wow=item_info&id=15272

Лучше оставить дефисное написание как более привычное для основы относительного прилагательного "бритвенный". В этом случае дефис может обозначать **оттенок состояния.**

Раздельное написание "бритвенно острый" подходит **по смыслу** (степень признака через сравнение: острый, как бритва), но **не по форме**.

Сравнить: *общественно полезный* (но это область проявления признака, полезный для общества), детски наивный (сравнение, но здесь наречие на СКИ).

Да и вообще **для термина** дефисное написание более подходящее, чем раздельное.